# Circle/wheel ScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview

I'm having a hard time finding a widget I need in Flutter, which I thought wouldn't be that rare.
What I'm looking fore is something very similar to this:

[image]

Which is available at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/circle_wheel_scroll), but doesn't have the flexibility I'm looking for.

Ideally, the widget I'm looking for wouldn't end like this one (when you keep scrolling it would go back to the first element). Also, I intend on stacking concentric wheel ScrollViews with different diameters.

Comment: Have you thought about customizing the package yourself to get what you want?